# Inequality problem with two modulus

Tags: calculus, inequality

Solving the inequality

$|x -3|+|x + 2|<11$.

I am used to solving these with one modulus function, with two I have not been successful in reaching a correct answer.I attempted squaring
 both sides and soon realised this was not an efficient way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** consider $3$ cases:

$-\infty < x \leq -2$,

$-2 < x \leq 3$, and

$3 < x < \infty$.